# Remove duplicates from PHP array

Tags: php

My PHP script is returning some array and I would like to remove duplicates in that array. Can you please tell me how? I dont want to remove duplicates from MySQL, just from PHP. I saw some questions similar to this one, but I couldn find a way to implement answers.

My PHP:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 


$sql = "SELECT Grad, Predmet FROM lista";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $rows[] = $row; 
    }

mysqli_close($con);

$rows = (object) array('lista' => $rows);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

And script is returning this:

```
{"lista":[{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"informatika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"informatika"}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique)?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the duplicates in PHP? Google `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Public service announcement: **`array_unique` does not work in cases like this because the elements are themselves arrays**. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to populate spinners with values from PHP, that's why I dont want duplicates. Tnx

Comment: @Michael can you please answer Jon and Jacks questions. And also point out why none of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+duplicates+from+mysql+result+php helped and what you tried? I will leave this open for now but please note that we usually expect to learn about your scenario and what you tried. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$rows = (object) array('lista' => $rows);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

With this:

```
$lista = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $rows)));
echo json_encode((object) array('lista' => $lista));
```

Comment: I am having an issue, now when I implemented your solution, I am getting a number in front of my array. Why? Can I remove it? "11":{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"matematika"}

Comment: I did this: echo json_encode((object) array('lista' => array_values($lista))); and now is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

try this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
```

Exemple from the php.net documentation :

```
<?php
    $input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
    $result = array_unique($input);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: I added an example in my post

Comment: still I dont get it, how to implement in my case...sorry for bothering

Comment: @OlivierSoulet - You didn't try that on his array, or you'd know that it doesn't work.